# copy one row from one sheet to another row in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting errors and I can not see why.

I have an array
looks for matches from the array down a column.
When it matches it copys the used range of that row and paste it below the last row on another page.

```
Dim iCL As Integer, USCurRow As Integer, USlRow As Integer, USlCol As Integer, USlRow2 As Integer
Dim USCountryList(1 To 1) As String
Dim USCtry As String

USCountryList(1) = "Country1"

For iCL = 1 To UBound(USCountryList)

  USCtry = USCountryList(iCL)
  USlRow = Sheets("US Confirmed").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  USlCol = Sheets("US Confirmed").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  USlRow2 = Sheets("World Confirmed").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For USCurRow = 2 To USlRow
       If Sheets("US Confirmed").Cells(USCurRow, 1) = USCtry Then
         Sheets("World Confirmed").Range(Cells(USlRow2 + 1, 1), Cells(USlRow2 + 1, USlCol)) = _
         Sheets("US Confirmed").Range(Cells(USCurRow, 1), Cells(USCurRow, USlCol))
       End If
    Next USCurRow
Next iCL
```

I keep getting an `application-defined or object-defined error` during the Copy part.
Stepping through the values of the variables appear to be valid:
hard coding them in as such:

```
  Sheets("World Confirmed").Range(Cells(268,1),cells(268,121))= _
  Sheets("US Confirmed").Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(3, 121))
```

Generates same `application-defined or object-defined error` error.

I have also tried `range select. selection copy`  `range select selection paste`
 and still running into an error

Comment: `Sheets("World Confirmed").Range(Cells(USlRow2 + 1, 1), Cells(USlRow2 + 1, USlCol))` itself is an object. You want to assign values to this object. I don't know how it is for `Range` but for `Cells` you can use assign a value to a kind of `Formula` or `Value` property/attribute.

Comment: @Tuckbros  not too sure what is meant by this. the verbiage is a bit over my head.

Comment: I just wanted to say, you have to choose the property of the range you want to update. You want to assign the ̀Value` of the source Range to the `Value` of the taget Range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is caused by your unqualified `Worksheet.Cells()` property.

In case you aren't familiar with *object qualification*, let's take a snippit from the [Microsoft documentation for the `Worksheet.Cells` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells):

> ### Syntax
>
> *expression*.Cells
>
> *expression* A variable that represents a Worksheet object.
>
> ...
>
> Using this property without an object qualifier returns a Range object that represents all the cells on the **active worksheet**

So in your line
`Sheets("World Confirmed").Range(Cells(USlRow2 + 1, 1), Cells(USlRow2 + 1, USlCol)) = _
         Sheets("US Confirmed").Range(Cells(USCurRow, 1), Cells(USCurRow, USlCol))`
the `Range()` property is qualified to `Sheets("World Confirmed")` and `Sheets("US Confirmed")` but your `Cells()` properties that are defining your start and end cells for your range are not.

If you qualify your `Cells()` properties to the relevant sheet your runtime error will cease but you will likely find the values won't be assigned to `Sheet1` as expected.

Using the `.Value` property on each range should resolve this, like so:

```
For USCurRow = 2 To USlRow
       If Sheets("US Confirmed").Cells(USCurRow, 1) = USCtry Then
         Sheets("World Confirmed").Range(Sheets("World Confirmed").Cells(USlRow2 + 1, 1), Sheets("World Confirmed").Cells(USlRow2 + 1, USlCol)).Value = _
         Sheets("US Confirmed").Range(Sheets("US Confirmed").Cells(USCurRow, 1), Sheets("US Confirmed").Cells(USCurRow, USlCol)).Value
       End If
    Next USCurRow
```

To improve readability and maintainability I'd suggest assigning your worksheets to a variable like so:

```
Dim SourceSheet as Worksheet
Dim DestinationSheet as Worksheet

Set SourceSheet = Thisworkbook.Sheets("US Confirmed")
Set DestinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("World Confirmed")

    For USCurRow = 2 To USlRow
       If Sheets("US Confirmed").Cells(USCurRow, 1) = USCtry Then
         DestinationSheet.Range(DestinationSheet.Cells(USlRow2 + 1, 1), DestinationSheet.Cells(USlRow2 + 1, USlCol)).Value = _
         SourceSheet.Range(SourceSheet.Cells(USCurRow, 1), SourceSheet.Cells(USCurRow, USlCol)).Value
       End If
    Next USCurRow
```

Comment: @Samual Everson Thank you so much, not only did you fix the issue, you enlightened me. I used to always slap `.value` onto pretty much everything, but I took a hiatus for a year or two from doing any vba, when I resumed I got lazy.    For the record, I did  have variables set for the workbooks, but took them away in case they were partly to blame. I have other subs that are called and they can call this one and I wanted to make sure it wasn;t being passed along and being changed. (Was trying everything before posting)

Comment: @BillFlippen I think you've taken some good debugging steps there! I thought it worth mentioning, there is no real benefit in using the `integer` data type any more - I couldn't find the MSDN page that points this out but I did find [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/9663006) that explains why very well AND also has a link and quote from the elusive MSDN page. :)